# Eclipse IDE: complete class member names with "this." prefix

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

For consistency I want to add **"this."** prefix to all classes members. I have done it when I wrote the code, mostly.

How can I get Eclipse to add **"this."** to the members I forgot.

I found that Java Editor Coding style has a check option for that, but when I clean up, or format the code the prefix is not added where it is missing.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @SuperHornet I want all the references to class members to be prefixed with "this." so the code is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clean Up** does exactly what it's told to do, but by default it doesn't include qualifying field accesses. In the Preferences dialog Under Java->Code Style->Clean Up, you have to create your own profile and set it to do so if you want the **Clean Up** action to do this.

[image]